# Storing data into History/Audit table

Tags: database, postgresql, audit-trail

I'm trying to figure out on how the data needs to be stored into History/audit/version table on operations like `INSERT`,`UPDATE` and `DELETE`

Let's say I have a master table with below columns:
PID,PRODUCT and DESCRIPTION

| PID | PRODUCT | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Keyboard | Normal |

For versioning purpose I have a History/Version table mirrored from master table with extra columns as below:
VERSION,PID,PRODUCT,DESCRIPTION,VALID FROM and VALID TO

I'm not able to figure what kind of approach I need to follow for storing data into this mirrored table for each of `INSERT`,`UPDATE` and `DELETE` operations when they happen.

Basically need to define the data flow in history table for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` operations.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Use trigger on the master table. There is an example here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) *Example 43.4. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Function for Auditing*.